# Управление enthernet sheild для arduino

Tags: клиент-сервер, arduino, микроконтроллеры

Сделал веб сервер, но хочу загружать html и css с sd карты, т.к на ардуино не хватает памяти даже для такого кода

```
    client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");        
    client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
    client.println("Connection: close");              
    client.println();
    client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");        
    client.println("<html>");            
    client.println("<head>");    
    client.println("<meta name=viewport content=width=device-width, initial-scale=1>");
    client.println("<meta charset=""utf-8"">");   
    client.println("<title>Панель управления</title>");    
    client.println("</head>");          
    client.println("<body style=margin:0;border:0;>");           
    client.print("<h1 align=center style=color:#555;font-family:Arial;>Умный дом</h1>");       
    client.print("<hr>");   
    client.print("<h2 align=center style=color:#555;font-family:Arial;>Cветодиод</h2>");  
    client.print("<a href=\"/$1\" style=color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;><div style=background-color:#555;font-size:50px;width:100px;height:50px;font-family:Arial;margin:auto;border-radius:20px;margin-bottom:20px;>On</div></a>");       
    client.print("<a href=\"/$2\" style=color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;><div style=background-color:#555;font-size:50px;width:100px;height:50px;font-family:Arial;margin:auto;border-radius:20px;margin-bottom:20px;>Off</div></a>");           
    client.print("<hr>");   
    client.print("<h2 align=center style=color:#555;font-family:Arial;>RGB Cветодиод</h2>");  
    client.print("<a href=\"/$3\" style=color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;><div style=background-color:#f00;font-size:50px;width:100px;height:50px;font-family:Arial;margin:auto;border-radius:20px;margin-bottom:20px;>R</div></a>");       
    client.print("<a href=\"/$4\" style=color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;><div style=background-color:#0f0;font-size:50px;width:100px;height:50px;font-family:Arial;margin:auto;border-radius:20px;margin-bottom:20px;>G</div></a>");              
    client.print("<hr>");  
    client.println("</body>");   
    client.println("</html>");                 
    break;
```

Просто скажите как реализовать загрузку html и css с sd.

Заранее спасибо!:)

Comment: "Даже такой код" можно здорово сжать, если выводить **одним** принтом (ведь вызов -- тоже код) и вынести значения `style`' в CSS, чтобы они не дублировались.

Comment: Уже сжал но памяти всё же мало.

Comment: Вот неплохой туториал на английском [Arduino SD Card Web Server](https://startingelectronics.org/tutorials/arduino/ethernet-shield-web-server-tutorial/SD-card-web-server/).

Comment: Какой памяти? RAM, ROM, storage?